# Vectors layers wont merge - integer instead of integer 64 error. Refactor fails to change

Tags: qgis, merge, integer

I am merging a few vector files (all polygone) but an error keeps popping up:

> POP1997 *(my attribute data)* field in layer area_houston.shp *(the layer i made)* has different data type then in other layers *(Integer64 instead of Integer)*

I am using QGIS 3.10.

I tried refactor fields to change Integer64 to Integer but when I save the file it is again in Integer64...

Please advise!

Comment: Did you try outputting the refactored layer as file? And does this issue then also exist? Or is it only when you save the created temporary layer?

Comment: I actually never use the save as temporary layer function. I am not an experienced qgis user and the computers on my university crash a lot during gis actions. Better save then sorry :)\

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem. I was successful with the following workaround:

- Open the attribute table of integer64 layer
- Create a new column and enter data -- I just entered an arbitrary ID -- selecting integer and making sure the length is less than 10 (as below):

[image: Screenshot of new attribute column window, QGIS]

- Select the features from the layer you want to merge, right click the layer and go to *Export > Save Selected Features As...*
- From here, you can check or uncheck the attributes you want to save. When I exported only "id3" and "integer_te" the vector layer had the same shape data but the layer was now classed as integer, rather than integer64.

[image: Screenshot of QGIS export features window]

The merge then ran successfully with this new layer.